# How to handle users who don't remember if they signed up via Facebook OR Google into my app?

Tags: ios, node.js, facebook, facebook-graph-api, google-signin

I am working on an app which allows users to sign up either manually via an email/password combination OR facebook OR google signup.

I am using their respective libraries on iOS which gets me the token from FB or Google whichever they choose. The app sends this token to my backend. On the backend side, I validate the token via the respective third party and if valid, I get the user's ID from the third party. I use this ID to identify the user in my database. In the database, I also store this user's email.

My problem arises when a user let's say deleted the app and reinstalls it and then forgets if they signed up via facebook or google login. Let's say they had originally signed up using facebook and now after reinstalling, they tap the signin via google button.
Now when the backend receives the new google token and I validate it, I get the ID of the user from google. Since this ID is different that the original ID of the user who had signed up via facebook, technically this is a completely different user. Also since the original user's email is already saved in the database, I can't create a duplicate user with the same email.

What's the right way to go around this situation?
Should the user be shown an information error telling them that they had originally signed up via Facebook and they should use that?

Comment: After Login Via Google/FB get User data like email and Name etc.. login via this credentials If next time login via any other method check the email id is exists in db or not if exist then login by that email id ; by which user login via google/fb or id method will be same.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using the Facebook ID to identify users in your database, use an id-column with auto increment integer. This way you get your own unique ID for each user. With this approach it is possible to map multiple single-sign-on ID:s, such as the users google ID and facebook ID, to the same user. Then use your own ID to identify users inside your app.

Comment: I do have a seperate column which is a UUID field meant specifically within my app's use. How would I map a the same user from facebook login to the same user from google? Like currently i have a column called auth_id which stores the 3rd party's ID and another column called userid which is my in app ID. Should I have something else?

Comment: Instead of having the same column for both facebook and google id, just have a separate for each, like facebook_id and google_id.

Comment: You also get an access token or something like this to fetch data about user from facebook and google right? this should also be saved in separate columns, facbook_token and google_token. There is nothing stopping you from letting users connect both their facebook account and google account to one single account in your app. You can match their email to find correct account.

Comment: ok. even if I have seperate columns, I still don't understand how when user logs in via google, my backend can somehow figure out that this user is the same as the other user which signed up via facebook. I could link it via the email address being the same for both accounts but that's a security issue as anyone can sign someone else up via their google email.

Comment: Lets say they sign up with facebook. You create a new row with your unique id, facebook id and email. Then when they sign in with google you can check for existing account by matching email. If they dont give you their email there is no way of knowing if they already have an account in your app or not

Comment: from my research, I have found that storing the facebook and google access accounts is discouraged. http://security.stackexchange.com/questions/72475/should-we-store-accesstoken-in-our-database-for-oauth2

Comment: @PranoyC you can update that db row if user is coming from different social path

Comment: Well you have to keep the token safe and check if it expires. I am sure there are guidelines on how to do this on facebooks and googles developer pages.

Comment: yea but that opens a security hole doesn't it? like lets say Bob doesn't actually have a facebook account. Bob signs up to my app via google. Malory (malicious party) signs up Bob to facebook via Bob's gmail email. Now malory can go to my app, signin with that facebook acount. Now since your suggestion is to match via email, Malory is able to see Bob's data. This is a security issue isn't it?

Comment: I think you don't need to store previous social tokens,if yes then why?

Comment: Well you cant let them manually enter an email when signing in via single-sign-on services. You get their email after they authenticate through google or facebook. That way Malory has to know Bobs facebook password to be able to sign in with his email.

Comment: @Yatendra yes, I have another column auth_type which tells me which social path the user signed up with. storing the token is possible but that still doesn't really help in this situation. Issue is about how to match the google user to the facebook user.

Comment: you can match that user with email id,because fb and google both returns email id

Comment: The process should be like this: Bob chooses to sign in with facebook -> he gets redirected to facebook login page -> he enters his credentials -> he gets redirected back to your website along with a token -> you use the token to get his email -> save in database. The process might be sluightly different depending in sso-service but you get the idea.

Comment: @Marcus sorry, I meant something else. I mean that since Bob doesn't have a facebook account, anyone can go to facebook and create an account by putting Bob's email. Facebook does send a "verification email" to Bob's email but that doesn't discourage Malory from still continuing to use that facebook account to sign up in my app. The facebook and google APIs do have a "verified" true/false attribute which I am checking.

Comment: @Marcus would you mind joining the chat? it's getting a bit long for the comments. I appreciate it.

Comment: Well if Malory can create a facebook account with bobs email without actually having access to that email, that is a serious security hole in FACEBOOK and i doubt that this is the case.

Comment: @Marcus yes that's what I thought too but if you google "facebook someone else used my email" you find a lot of such cases. that's why I am a bit confused

Comment: @Marcus this one for example:
https://www.facebook.com/help/community/question/?id=808750535838219

Comment: I don't really think that you can do anything about that in that case, and I don't think there is any other way to match accounts than by email. Atleast that how I did it when I did an application like this some time ago.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/133415/discussion-between-marcus-and-pranoy-c).